# Flattening previous history records in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like `[ id, group, reading, reading_date ]` that contains reading values for a particular group that are filled out periodically throughout the day.

I want to generate results that look like `[ id, group, reading, reading_date, prev_reading, prev_date ]` where the previous reading/date are the latest values for the group that are at least one day older than `reading_date`

Basically it seems like I should be able to self-join and get the id of the reading at least one day old, but I haven't been able to find a combination that actually works.

```
select h1.id, h1.group, h1.reading, h1.reading_date, h2.id prev_id
from history h1, history h2
where h2.id = (
  select ...
)
```

I've also tried a handful of variants using analytic functions, but `rank` and `lag` don't seem to work because the offset between the records is variable, and I'm not seeing how to get `first_value` to do what I want.

thanks for any pointers in the right directly, my Oracle analytic skills are fairly lacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT h1.id, h1.group, h1.reading, h1.reading_date
     , MAX(h2.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY h2.reading_date DESC) AS prev_id
     , MAX(h2.reading) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY h2.reading_date DESC) AS prev_reading
     , MAX(h2.reading_date) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY h2.reading_date DESC) AS prev_date
  FROM history h1 LEFT JOIN history h2
    ON h1.group = h2.group
   AND h1.reading_date - 1 >= h2.reading_date
 GROUP BY h1.id, h1.group, h1.reading, h1.reading_date;
```

This will get the most recent record in `h2` that is at least one day older than the record in h1. Keep in mind that `h1` will have older records as well as the latest ones.

Comment: That seems to work at least in part, though I'm having trouble getting it to perform acceptably. The actual tables I'm working with are more complicated than the example I gave, I was trying to give a simpler version for people to work with. Your strategy works if I limit the data (it's a large table), but one part I didn't mention is I need to also join for 2 days back, and adding another join seems to completely kill it. I'll keep experimenting though

Comment: For my particular instance adding a lower bound on the joined date search (`AND h1.reading_date - 10 < h2.reading_date`) significantly improves the performance, and I was able to join the table a second time to get the ID from two days back as well

Comment: Great to hear that my answer was at least a little helpful.